# A function "update" which let s i v returns s[v |-> i] in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell, and this is a simple question in haskell.

I'm just trying to write a function update with the following signature such that 
`update s i v` returns the state update `s[v |-> i]`. i.e. state obtained from `s` by updating the value of `v` to `i`.

My code here is :

```
type Num = Integer
type Var = String
type Z = Integer
type T = Bool
type State = Var -> Z
```

And what I'm trying to write is a function

```
update :: State -> Z -> Var -> State
update s i v =  v i
```

But when I compile this, ghci gives that

```
couldn't match expected type 'Z -> State' with actual type '[Char]'. The function 'v' is applied to one argument, but its type 'Var' has none
```

What confuses me is that I don't want a `Z -> State` here. Could anyone give me any hints? I'm sorry if I did not make this question clear. I started learning Haskell yesterday :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return a function representing your new state (the state seems to be a function from `Var -> Z`:

```
update :: State -> Z -> Var -> State
update oldState i v = newState
    where newState v'
             | v == v' = i
             | otherwise = oldState v
```

---

let's see the main issues with your version:

- `v i` would indicate that you want to evaluate `v` at `i` - but `v` is a `Var ~ String` so you get the compiler error (saying that `Var` has no arguments)
- you don't even use `s` this should indicate that you either really don't need it or you forgot to use it ;)

Comment: Thank you @Carsten ! I understand this now. Thanks for the help

Comment: no problem - if you feel that this answers your question you can opt to mark it as one so others see that this question is finished